# Couldn't find nested source for path when running inner hit query for has parent query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

```
we are migrating to elastic search 8 and when we are trying to fetch the data of parent document inner hits using has parent query .elastic search returning exception when runnning innerhits for has parent query.
```

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/inner-hits-in-has-parent-giving-error-couldnt-find-nested-source-for-path-currentcompany/318232

Comment: give more details: documents, mapping.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

bellow query giving me same error:, I had to pick parent document by using a field instead of **_id**

```
GET /user_data_factory/_search?from=0&size=20
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "relation_type": "uinsp"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "userInspirer": "63bef9f9a8c98000126589eb"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "minimum_should_match": 1,
                            "should": [
                               {
                                "has_parent": {
                                  "parent_type": "user",
                                  "query": {
                                    "match": {
                                      "_id": "63bd1ff29510390012760322"
                                    }
                                  },
                                   "inner_hits": {
                                    "_source": ["id"]
                                  }
                                }
                              }]
                            
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }]
              
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

using field instead of _id

```
GET /user_data_factory/_search?from=0&size=20
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "relation_type": "uinsp"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "userInspirer": "63bef9f9a8c98000126589eb"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "minimum_should_match": 1,
                            "should": [
                               {
                                "has_parent": {
                                  "parent_type": "user",
                                  "query": {
                                    "match": {
                                      "id": "63bd1ff29510390012760322"
                                    }
                                  },
                                   "inner_hits": {
                                    "_source": ["id"]
                                  }
                                }
                              }]
                            
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }]
              
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```